# The instance member 'locale' can't be accessed in an initialize in the A class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class A and also I have a delegate of class A.
I have some getters like:

```
String get appTitle {
    return localizedValues[locale.languageCode]!['welcome']!;
  }

  String get timeIsUpTitle {
    return localizedValues[locale.languageCode]!['hello']!;
  }
```

So here you can see the codes are duplicated. So I want to replace  **localizedValues[locale.languageCode]!** this, to some value like selectedLanguage as an example. When I try this, it gives an error:

```
The instance member 'locale' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression
```

How can I solve this problem?

my class for example,

```
class A {
A(this.locale)

final Locale locale;
String get timeIsUpTitle {
    return localizedValues[locale.languageCode]!['welcome']!;
  }

some properties...
.
.
}
```

Also If you have any suggestion to avoid duplicate (string get string get......) I can take them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a method which will get that information using a paramenter:

```
class A {
  A(this.locale);

  final Locale locale;

  String timeIsUpTitle2(String selectedLanguage) { // here pass the parameter you want to use

    return localizedValues[selectedLanguage]!['welcome']!; // then get the value

  }

}
```

Comment: what If I do not want to write parameters in UI (I mean what if I want to just get necessary string from the file)

Comment: The thing is that dart wont allow you to access instance members (the locale variable) in initializer (in the Class constructor), this is why you should approach this issue in a different way. You will find more information here: https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=implicit_this_reference_in_initializer#implicit_this_reference_in_initializer

Comment: it is useful but also my problem and question continue in different way, If you want to see... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71872029/how-can-i-compound-getters-in-dart-to-avoid-duplication