# how can I compound getters in dart to avoid duplication

Tags: flutter, class, dart, getter

I have lots of getters for localizations (they are coming from the json file for example) such as:

```
  String get start {
    return localizedValues[locale.languageCode]!['start']!;
  }

  String get hours {
    return localizedValues[locale.languageCode]!['hours']!;
  }

  String get minutes {
    return localizedValues[locale.languageCode]!['minutes']!;
  }

  String get seconds {
    return localizedValues[locale.languageCode]!['seconds']!;
  }
```

So I want to compound them since they use some common codes (I tried to create final someWord = commonCode; but It did not work, so I wanted to ask)

Now, If I want to reach them, I use myClass.of(context).start for example. So, in the end, I will reach using the same way but in the class which is above, I will not do any duplication If you help me. So, I need your help to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would recommend using a data class to hold localisation data instead of just a Map, or using a package such as [i10n](https://pub.dev/packages/i10n_translator) to do the translations for you.**

There are a couple of ways you can shorten this code. For starters, you can extract `localizedValues[locale.languageCode]!` to its own getter, like this:

```dart
Map<String, String> get localeValues => localizedValues[locale.languageCode]!;
```

Then all your methods become a bit shorter:

```dart
String get seconds {
  return localeValues['seconds']!;
}
```

Additionally, you can shorten your getters by removing the function body and using an arrow function instead, like I did above for the `localeValues`:

```dart
String get seconds => localeValues['seconds']!;
```

Do this for all your getters, and your code is now shorter.

Comment: Map<String, String> get localeValues => localizedValues[locale.languageCode]!; <<< I wanted this actually, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method, and shorten the code:

```
  String getTime(String languageCode, String time) {

    return localizedValues[languageCode]![time]!;

  }

  getTime("1529", "seconds");
  getTime("859", "mitutes");
  getTime("9632", "hours");
```

Comment: I do not want to use strings in UI, I just want to call them. So I need different technique

Comment: It just an example actually, you can pass what you need. Which type of data you want to use?

Comment: I use json, and I use localization for the only strings (title etc) in my app. So I do not want to use like Text(getTitle(appBar)). Instead of this, I want to use Text(localization.appBar). Simple actually.